# Update functions in Hash Table in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I am a beginner in Racket and I am trying to updare a hash table using hash-update! where the value is a mutable set. Below are the code lines:

```
(hash-update! hash key (curryr set-add! new_val) (mutable-set 1))
```

However I receive an error

```
 expected: set?
given: #<void>
argument position: 1st
other arguments...:
  x: 2
```

where I tried 2 as the new_val

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the updater is supposed to be a function that takes a value as input and produces a new value output. Since the set is mutable and you're using [`set-add!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fset..rkt)._set-add!))) to mutate it, the "updater" isn't returning a new value, just mutating the old one and producing void.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Mutable sets as values, mutate them separately, not inside [`hash-update!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._hash-update%21%29%29).
2. Immutable sets as values, use a functional updater inside [`hash-update!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._hash-update%21%29%29).

Since you specified you want the values as mutable sets, I will show (1).

The most basic thing you can do is [`hash-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-ref%29%29) to get a mutable-set, and then use [`set-add!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fset..rkt)._set-add!))) on that.

```
(set-add! (hash-ref hash key) new-val)
```

However, this doesn't work when there is no mutable-set value for that key yet. It needs to be added to the table when it doesn't exist yet which why is why you have the `(mutable-set 1)` failure-result argument. The solution to this isn't [`hash-update!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._hash-update%21%29%29), it's [`hash-ref!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._hash-ref%21%29%29).

```
(set-add! (hash-ref! hash key (mutable-set 1)) new-val)
```

Although it would probably be better if you wrapped the failure-result in a thunk

```
(set-add! (hash-ref! hash key (λ () (mutable-set 1))) new-val)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was stuck for a long time on this. Thanks a lot !